# ASP .NET Core 2.1 React Template can't talk to controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Perhaps this is my lack of knowledge in how this works (I'm an intern trying to help the team convert from 2.0 >> 2.1 template), but I have am having issues with this new **ASP.NET Core 2.1 React Template**, and publishing it on our IIS Server.

As a proof-of-concept, I just created a new project out of the box, add an easy /api/weather call, published as `Release` (read somewhere that was important), dropped it on the company's IIS dev server... and assumed that when I pointed the web app at the contents of the folder, it would just work (like it did with ASP.NET Core 2.0). However, it complains about being unable to run/install via npm when visiting the site... but **DOES** work if you instead point it at `/build` folder.

So great, we use the IIS Manager to point it at the `/build` folder, the site loads the static pages and such... but loses the capability to access the APIs within the controllers (such as `/api/sampledata/weather`) via fetch/axios. This is causing problems with other things (details unnecessary for this post), and so I was hoping someone else might have some insight into why the 2.1 template fails to work while the 2.0 did?

Oh, and I did update the dev machine we have from 2.0 >> 2.1, so everyone is running the same .NET Core version.

Any ideas? If there is more data necessary, please ask, happy to volunteer just about anything that isn't sensitive data.

For reference to what that error was I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:83:20
at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:224:22)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:262:24
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:178:20)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
if (npm.config.get('json')) {
^
```

Comment: If it works when you point it at the build directory then perhaps instead publish the build directory contents to the root.

Comment: A bit of investigation about this idea @Brad, and the create-react-app build process doesn't really permit the redirection of where the build directory contents. However, when trying to just copy-pasta the contents upwards with all the rest of the `*.dll`s (as it appears with the ASP .NET Core 2.0 template), it just doesn't work, yielding the error above, as well (as though having the `*.dll` files in the root directory causes problems). I imagine this is just due to lack of knowledge about how this all works, I was hoping it would mean there is an obvious answer I overlooked :(